# UIView Flip Transition only occurring once

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a UIView containing two other UIViews.  I am trying to make them flip on a button press.  Here is my code to flip them in the button actions:

```
- (IBAction)btMapView:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView transitionFromView:mView1 toView:m_MapView duration:3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:NULL];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (IBAction)btListView:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView transitionFromView:m_MapView toView:mView1 duration:3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight completion:NULL];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I initialize m_MapView in my viewDidLoad as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [m_MapView setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];
    [m_MapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [m_MapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    region.center.latitude = 42.761738 ;
    region.center.longitude = -71.463180;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [m_MapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    m_MapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [m_MapView setDelegate:self];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = 42.761738;
    zoomLocation.longitude = -71.463180;

    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, .25*METERS_PER_MILE, .25*METERS_PER_MILE);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [m_MapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];

    m_MapView.autoresizingMask =
    (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

    [m_MapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];

    DisplayMap * myLoc = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
    myLoc.title = @"myLoc";
    myLoc.subtitle = @"Main Office";
    myLoc.coordinate = region.center;
    [m_MapView addAnnotation:myLoc];
}
```

And my second view just has a label on it.

When I touch the btMapView button, the flip occurs to the other view, but when I press the btListView button it does not flip back.

Can anyone shed some light on what I copuld be doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

Got this to work by moving my code from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear and changing the two button methods to this:

```
- (IBAction)btMapView:(id)sender
{
    [UIView transitionFromView:mView1
                        toView:m_MapView
                      duration:1
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews 
                    completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)btListView:(id)sender
{
    [UIView transitionFromView:m_MapView
                        toView:mView1
                      duration:1
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews 
                    completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: You don't need to put transitionFromView inside a begin/commitAnimations pair ...

Comment: So, I did remove those lines and just left the transitionFromView and it does flip once and then flip back, but the view is blank after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
- (IBAction)btMapView:(id)sender
{
    [mView1.superview addSubview: m_MapView];
    [UIView transitionFromView:mView1 toView:m_MapView duration:3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews completion: ^(BOOL finished) { [mView1 removeFromSuperview]; }];
}

- (IBAction)btListView:(id)sender
{
    [m_MapView.superview addSubview: mView1];
    [UIView transitionFromView:m_MapView toView:mView1 duration:3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews completion:^(BOOL finished) { [m_MapView removeFromSuperview]; }];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that but the views transition once and then the views are blank.

Comment: @LilMoke: Did you actually try my code?  I added a completion block.  Try it.

Comment: I added the code you sent, but it does the same thing... the view is blank after the first time.

Comment: @LilMoke ... edited my code .. try that.  If that doesn't work then im lost .. cos it works on my machine! :D

Comment: Hmm I also notice that I use UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews in my options .. will edit the above.

Comment: Still does not work, plus you have a couple typos in your code, removeFromSuperview has no capital v in both methods. And m)MapView and mView1 do not have a view, i.e.: m_MapView.view.superview is not right.

Comment: @LilMoke: That addSubview/removeFromSuperview mistake has left me horrifically confused in the past ;)  Can you give more context then?  What is mView1?  What is m_MapView?  Where are you initialising these views?  Inside a viewDidLoad?  or viewDidAppear?

Comment: I have updated my code above with my viewDidLoad.  That is where I take care of the MapView and the other view just has a label on it.

Comment: @LilMoke: Then your likely problem is that viewDidLoad only ever gets called once ... move the code to viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear ...

Comment: Hmm, I moved my viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear and no dice, still does the same thing.

Comment: For what is's worth, I got it to work by moving the code from the viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear and changing the two button methods to the code above in my original post.

Comment: there is no need to remove and add views just send one behind the other if they are the same size and not transparent, to fix the issue of having blank views after first transition, you should use UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews to redraw them after the toggle. You could probably just hide them too. P.S. I know it's a late comment, but I noticed there was no answer that worked for me except for laying out the subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code at UIButton action, It is woking properly:

```
    SecondView *second=[[SecondView alloc] init];
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:second.view duration:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight completion:nil];
```

Here SecondView is name of SecondView.